# ¿en python la función settimeout(n), es para establecer el tiempo de conexión?

Tags: python, socket

```
from socket import *

s=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind(("localhost",9000))
s.listen(5)
s.settimeout(5.0)
while True:
    c,a=s.accept()
    print "servidor \n"
    print "recived connection from ", a

    c.send("hello %s\n"%a[0])
    c.close()
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con tiempo de conexión?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`settimeout` nos ofrece la posibilidad de definir tres comportamientos o modos diferentes para nuestro socket:

- **`settimeout(None)`:** por defecto el socket está en **modo bloqueante**, es decir, las operaciones bloqueantes como `recv` no van a retornar hasta que no se completen (en el caso de `recv`  hasta que no exista algo que leer en el buffer), quedando el proceso a la espera en ese punto, a no ser que el sistema lance alguna excepción. Equivalente a `sock.setblocking(True)`.
- **`settimeout(0.0)`**: establece el socket en **modo no bloqueante**, lo que significa que si la operación no se puede llevar a cabo de forma inmediata se lanza una excepción (la cual depende del sistema operativo). Equivalente a `sock.setblocking(False)`.
- **`settimeout(s)`**: donde `s` es un float mayor que 0. Define el socket en **modo *timeout***, cualquier operación bloqueante lanzará una excepción [`socket.timeout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.timeout) si no se puede completar en ***s*** segundos (si el sistema no lanza otra excepción antes). Son implementados como sockets no bloqueantes a nivel del sistema.

La diferencia fundamental de los sockets no bloqueantes es a grandes rasgos  que `send()`, `recv()`, `connect()` o `accept()` puede retornar sin haber hecho absolutamente nada. La clave por tanto suele estar en saber cuando el socket está listo para realizar la operación, para lo cual lo más eficiente y menos doloroso es usar [`select`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html) (en vez de intentar manejar excepciones).